# Protobuf-Net: implementing server, rpc controller and rpc channel

Tags: c#, network-programming, protocol-buffers, rpc, protobuf-net

I am trying to implement a set of services which are temporarily implemented with tcp but will eventually be moved to udp. I had my proto file converted to the rpc interface, but this requires a server, rpc channel, and rpc controller.

I don't know what rpc controller and rpc channel are, much less how to implement them. Can anyone explain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I looked briefly at protobuf-remote which seems to have never been completed and only does tcp. I also have been looking at gRPC which might work... Not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a protobuf RPC in C++, but it might help a bit.

The `controller` generally controls the status of the message, like `Failed`. Example [here](https://github.com/madwyn/libpbrpc/blob/master/src/pbrpc/ControllerRPC.hh).

In my implementation, there is no `channel` at all. I would imagine that `channel` takes care of keeping the message flows' consistency, e.g., an internal session state. So the server can accept multiple requests at the same time and response correspondingly. (I could be wrong about this)

Take a look of my bare bone RPC middle ware [here](https://github.com/madwyn/pbrpc), it's really simple, only 8 source files.

Comment: Thanks! It's nice to at lest have an example. I appreciate it.